# I would like to insert my sqlite data into a custom list view.how can i do this.i can insert into a list view,but i can't insert in custom list view

Tags: android, sqlite

here some of my mainactivity code where i insert my sqlite information into a list view.anyone can tell me how can i insert data into a custom list view.here anyone can tell me how can i do this.

MainActivity.java

```
ListView lst;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lst=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_xml);

    lst.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ContactActivity.class);
            Bundle b=new Bundle();
            b.putInt("position",i);
            intent.putExtras(b);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });


}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add_contact_menu,menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.add_contact:
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,ContactActivity.class));
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {

    DBHelper db=new DBHelper(this);

    ArrayList<String> names=new ArrayList<String>();


    for (int i=0;i<db.getAllcontact().size();i++)
        names.add("Total Earn:"+db.getAllcontact().get(i).getName()+"\nCategorey:"+db.getAllcontact().get(i).getAddress()+"\nSAVE"+db.getAllcontact().get(i).getPhone());

    ArrayAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,names);

    lst.setAdapter(adapter);
    super.onResume();
}
```

Comment: What's custom about the custom ListView? Procedure should be all the same. Or do you mean a custom Adapter?

Comment: yes i mean a custom adapter...can you help me please.

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer right now, but this is a good read
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews

Comment: oki.when you will free then please help me,,and advance thanks